# Update database by click on the value

Tags: jquery

I want to manage my image gallery. There is a image management page for that. each and every image has default flag as '0'. When I click on that '0' in image management page it changed to '1'. It works perfectly.

What I want is I want to update flag value of database to '1' at the same time.How can I do that.

My code is

```
    <?php

 # Init the MySQL Connection
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("selfie") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 # Prepare the SELECT Query
  $selectSQL = 'SELECT * FROM `image_upload`  INNER JOIN user_table
ON image_upload.user_id=user_table.user_id WHERE flag="0" ORDER BY timestamp DESC';
 # Execute the SELECT Query
  if( !( $selectRes = mysql_query( $selectSQL ) ) ){
    echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();
     }else{
        ?>
<table border="2">

      <thead id="head">
    <tr>
      <th id="head">User name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
     <?php
      if( mysql_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 ){
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
      }else{
            while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) ){
              echo "<tr>
              <td>{$row['user_name']}</td>
              <td>{$row['category']}</td>
          <td>{$row['description']}</td>
          <td ><img src='uploads/".$row['image']."'width=300px height=200px></td>

        <td onclick='changeText(this)'>{$row['flag']}</td>
          </tr>\n";

        }
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <?php

  }

?>
```

My script is

```
    <script>
function changeText(id) {

id.innerHTML = "1";

} 
</script>
```

Comment: You need to send an AJAX request from the function changeText().
i don't want to give it all over here, you will miss the fun in learning AJAX.
visit http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: use ajax with jquery to change your value in database

Comment: I tried. But It's not work. Other thing is I can't find the error also. Because I'm new for web developing

Answer (score 0):

It's always good practice to separate your JS from your markup. Therefore start by changing:

```
 <td onclick='changeText(this)'>{$row['flag']}</td>
```

To:

```
 <td class="change-text" data-user="{$row['user_name']}">{$row['flag']}</td>
```

Then use the following updated code to change your flags. Please note that the code contains an ajax call and that your flag on the page is only updated after a successful DB update:

```
$(function() {
    $('.change-text').on('click', function() {
        var text = $(this).text().trim();
        if( text === "0" ) {
            $.post( 'updateText.php', {flag: 1,user_name:$(this).data('user')} )
            .done(function(data) {
                //depending on what is returned you may want to update the flag
                //if only you get the desired response
                $(this).html( 1 );
            });
         }
    });
});
```

**Finally,** write a new PHP, `updateText.php`, script that receives two parameters; `flag` and `user_name` (you could use `id` or your primary key instead of `user_name` if it's available) -- `$_POST['flag']` and `$_POST['user_name']` - and uses these to update the DB record.